# Как сократить php код?

Tags: php, оптимизация, sql

Здравствуйте, есть в БД таблица с именами, у каждого имени есть очередь 1,2,3 и т.д. Пхп выводит имю у кого очередь подошел по его айди выводим номер карты, и потом сразу же сохраняет очередь этого имени на последний (пример если последняя очередь 555 то добовляет +1 и сохраняет 556). Помогите этот код правильно сократить, ужасно тормозит.

```
$nU = mysql_query("SELECT id, usr, turn FROM tz_members WHERE  turn>0 ORDER BY  turn ASC LIMIT 1",$db); // вывод имени по очереди 
        if (!$nU)
            {echo "<p>База данных пуст</p>";
                exit (mysql_error());}
        if (mysql_num_rows($nU) > 0) //если все хорошо
                    {
                        $myrowNU = mysql_fetch_array($nU);
                        $nC = mysql_query("SELECT numberC FROM nomberC WHERE idUser=".$myrowNU['id']." ",$db); //вывод номер карточки по айди имени
                        if (!$nC)
                        {
                          echo "<p>База пуста</p>";
                          exit (mysql_error());
                        }
                if (mysql_num_rows($nC) > 0)
                    {
                        $myrowNC = mysql_fetch_array($nC);    
                    }
                        $nTurn = mysql_query("SELECT turn FROM tz_members WHERE  turn>".$myrowNU['turn']." ORDER BY  turn DESC LIMIT 1",$db); //вывод номер последней очереди
                            $myrowNTurn = mysql_fetch_array($nTurn);
                            $summNT = $myrowNTurn['turn']+1; //на полученный номер очереди добовляем 1 и сохраняем на последний 
                            mysql_query ("UPDATE tz_members SET turn=".$summNT." WHERE id=".$myrowNU['id']."", $db);

                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$nU = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `turn` FROM `tz_members` WHERE `turn`>0 ORDER BY `turn` ASC LIMIT 1",$db); // вывод имени по очереди 
if (!$nU)
    exit ("<p>База данных пуст</p>".mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($nU) > 0){
    $myrowNU = mysql_fetch_array($nU);
    $nC = mysql_query("SELECT numberC FROM nomberC WHERE idUser=".$myrowNU['id']." ",$db); //вывод номер карточки по айди имени
    if (!$nC)
        exit ("<p>База пуста</p>".mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($nC) > 0)
        $myrowNC = mysql_fetch_array($nC);    
    mysql_query ("UPDATE `tz_members` SET `turn`=IFNULL(uploaded,0)+1 WHERE turn>".$myrowNU['turn']." LIMIT 1", $db);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

**//UPD**

А вообще в одну строку так, и не нужно городить огород, остальное у тебя никак не используется!

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE tz_members SET turn=turn+1 WHERE turn>0", $db);
```

Это весь запрос в БД нужный тебе! Задача какая-то неправильная, опиши лучше, зачем ты что-то выводишь-то?

Comment: хотел чтоб юсеры выходили из БД по очереди, поэтому так придумал,)